# Android Twitpic Application -upload Images

Tags: android

I am doing project on uploading Images and to share that in twitter , I have Oauth and Twitpick Key can anyone send some sample on this. I have checked Grepcode but not clear,I have to complete today can anyone guide me plz.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [twitpicshare](http://code.google.com/p/twitpicshare/), you might be able to adapt the source code to your requirements.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Let me try with that . But ther it has Twitter username and password I have to user Oauth instead. and I have sample code below is the URL .                                                     http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.twitter4j/twitter4j-examples/2.1.3/twitter4j/examples/TwitpicOAuthImageUpload.java